# Div não aparece corretamente nos dispositivos diferenciados

Tags: css

Tenho a seguinte div:

```
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">    
  <div class="row">    
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center"><img src="imagens/interprete.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12  col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 text-center texto-descricao">
              <span class="titulo-conteudo">DIRETAMENTE DO BOREL</span><br>
              <span class="texto-conteudo">Wantuir foi escolhido o Melhor Intérprete do Grupo Especial e fatura Prêmio S@amba-Net 2019</span>
          </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">    
  <div class="row">    
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center"><img src="imagens/interprete.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12  col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 text-center texto-descricao">
              <span class="titulo-conteudo">DIRETAMENTE DO BOREL</span><br>
              <span class="texto-conteudo">Wantuir foi escolhido o Melhor Intérprete do Grupo Especial e fatura Prêmio S@amba-Net 2019</span>
          </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">    
  <div class="row">    
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center"><img src="imagens/interprete.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12  col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 text-center texto-descricao">
              <span class="titulo-conteudo">DIRETAMENTE DO BOREL</span><br>
              <span class="texto-conteudo">Wantuir foi escolhido o Melhor Intérprete do Grupo Especial e fatura Prêmio S@amba-Net 2019</span>
          </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Porém quando visualizo essa div no smartphone Moto G3 e em outro da Samsung Galaxy J4+ com a tela maior, essa div aparece em posições diferentes. Já tentei ajustá-la de seguinte forma:

```
.texto-descricao{
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: 13%; 
    background-color: #FFD400; 
    padding: 10px
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
    .texto-descricao{
        margin-top: -50px;
        width: 300px;     
        margin-left:30%;   
        background-color: #FFD400; 
        padding: 10px
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .texto-descricao{
        margin-top: -50px;
        width: 300px;     
        margin-left:30%;   
        background-color: #FFD400; 
        padding: 10px
    }
}
```

Mas não funcionou, somente no `max-width: 600px` fez efeito em ambos. Como posso fazer para que a div apareça na mesma posição independente do dispositivo? Já coloquei em `px`, mas também não funcionou!

Comment: Cara esse seu grid está muito estranho, vc não deve ir colocando uma `col` dentro da outra igual vc fez, vc até pode fazer `row>col>row>col` mas não `col>col>col` um `col` tem que ser filha de uma `row`.... antes de pensar em fazer esse @media, talvez fosse melhor vc revisar esse grid

Comment: Olá Hugo. Certo. Fiz o ajuste, mas mesmo assim está dando essa incompatibilidade. A linha principal tem 03 colunas e dentro de cada coluna fiz o que você sugeriu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As classes do Bootstrap `col`, `col-sm`, `col-md` etc., são classes para auxiliar em um design responsivo da sua aplicação. Provavalmente são estas que fazem com que a posição da suas div fiquem diferentes nos dispositivos que testou.

Não cheguei a ver a resolução dos dispositivos que mencionou, mas na div em que atribuiu `col-sm-7` por exemplo, caso o dispositivo com tela maior entre na categoria `sm` e seu dispositivo menor entre na categoria `xs`, a disposição dos elementos será diferente uma vez que o valor *default* das telas menores é o `col-xs-12` (a partir do Bootstrap 4 o `col-xs-*` deixou de ser usado, agora só usa `col-*`).

Se quer que suas divs apareçam na mesma posição independente se for dispositivo móvel ou desktop, apenas defina para o tamanho menor, no caso o `col-xs` ou `col` a depender da versão do Bootstrap.

Segue link de uma thread do SO que explica bem essa parte das colunas e os tamanhos no Bootstrap: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41795300/7380348

Comment: Certo Livio. Obrigado pelas dicas.